# domlistener on window.load event inside document.ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, maps

This code stopped working despite the fact that window.load works after ready.

$(document).ready(function () {
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function () { InitializeMap(); });

```
But If I write the code outside the ready function, it works fine.

$(document).ready(function () {
    InitializeMap(); });

This code also works nice.
```

Comment: Is there a question in there somewhere?

Comment: The question is .. Why I can't write window.load event in document ready event in this specific case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a jQuery related issue. jQuery uses its own internal deferred object to represent a list of "ready" callback functions. Within this deferred object there may or may not be timeouts set for various reasons, the `window.onload` is cancelled under some conditions, and more. jQuery does all of these things to ensure cross-browser consistency.  From the jQuery documentation:

> Note that although the DOM always becomes ready before the page is
>   fully loaded, it is usually not safe to attach a load event listener
>   in code executed during a .ready() handler. For example, scripts can
>   be loaded dynamically long after the page has loaded using methods
>   such as $.getScript(). Although handlers added by .ready() will always
>   be executed in a dynamically loaded script, the window's load event
>   has already occurred and those listeners will never run.

[Reference](https://api.jquery.com/ready/)

The plain JavaScript solution below works as you would expect since there isn't all that additional cruft that goes into jQuery's implementation of the same code:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function() {
    alert('custom event');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3"></script>
```